# MongoDB java driver, force insert null values, field case

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to use mongoDB java driver, I have mapped sample POJO class

```
public final class SamplePojo
{
    private ObjectId id;
    private String Name;
    private String Phone;

    public SamplePojo(String name, String phone)
    {
       this.Name = name;
       this.Phone = phone;
    }

    public ObjectId getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getPhone()
    {
       return Phone;
    }
}
```

I have following issues I could not fix:

1. When trying to insert null values, they are ignored and not insered into mongoDB, say:

   new SamplePojo("name", null);

In this case, only name would be inserted, and I need null values to be inserted as well, in mongoDB C# i seen it inserts null values by default.

2. When inserting, field names are saved starting with lower case, but I need them to start with upper case.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it?